# requires always-build package error

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to install **rvHtmlViewImportDXE7** I already installed **dclFrameViewerXE7** package but I still have this error

> [dcc32 Error] E2466 Never-build package '.rvHtmlViewImportDXE7'
>   requires always-build package 'dclFrameViewerXE7'

compiler can't find the installed dclFrameViewerXE7 ? any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: In project options for dclFrameViewerXE7, you need to change Build control from Rebuild as Needed to Explicit rebuild

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78159789/never-build-vs-always-build

Answer (score 3):

In project options for dclFrameViewerXE7, you need to change Build control from Rebuild as Needed to Explicit rebuild