# "Never build" vs "always build"

Tags: delphi

Related to:

> [dcc32 Error] E2466 Never-build package 'x' requires always-build
> package 'y'.

Could anyone comment on when "never build", "always build" is ACTUALLY useful?
The documentation says that packages that are seldom changed should be marked with "never build". But this is kinda pointless since you don't change the package anyway (so it will never be recompiled).

Why not mark all packages as "always build" and deal with the problem forever?

Comment: Some runtime packages like those for the VCL need to be stable and rebuilding them will cause problems. Similar errors are often due to not being able to find BPLs resulting in attempts to rebuild/recreate them.

Comment: Runtime packages you distribute and share with other installed applications should not be built when applications that use them are. Changes could break that sharing so such packages are usually never-build.

Comment: @Brian - So you mean that "never build" mainly applies to the Delphi VCL framework, and to the runtime packages?

Comment: The difference is who is owner of the package. If the package is part of your app, than you will want to rebuild it when something has changed in your code. If package contains some third party components, than you do not want to rebuild it each time. Because it can break other projects on your PC.

Comment: @Torbins - Yes, but if you don't change the 3rd party package, it won't be recompiled anyway. Or am I wrong? So, in this case, NeverBuild is still pointless.

Comment: @IceCold I am not 100% sure, but compilation setting change in main project may trigger recompile in package.